# Object reference not set to an instance of an object during members registeration in umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

hi i am new to umbraco

ive recent made a login and signup page and use umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member

login is working prefectly fine

but during registeration it gives error while checking for the previous existed users

here is the Register.aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using umbraco;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;

namespace membershipc
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        // Macro Parameters
        public int SuccessfulLoginPage { get; set; }

        // Member Type & Group
        private const string MembersType = "SiteMembers";
        private const string MembersGroup = "SiteMembers";

        // Error format
        private const string ErrorFormat = "<p class=\"formerror\">{0}</p>";

        protected void RegisterPlayer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do some server side checks just to be on the safe side
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbEmail.Text) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbPassword.Text) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbUsername.Text))
            {
                litError.Text = string.Format(ErrorFormat, "Please complete all fields");
                return;
            }

            // Check the user isn't already registered
            **if ((Member.GetMemberFromEmail(tbEmail.Text) == null) && (Member.GetMemberFromLoginName(tbUsername.Text) == null))**
            {
                // Set the member type and group
                var mt = MemberType.GetByAlias(MembersType);
                var addToMemberGroup = MemberGroup.GetByName(MembersGroup);

                //create the member, and set the password and email
                var m = Member.MakeNew(tbUsername.Text, mt, new User(0));
                m.Password = tbPassword.Text;
                m.Email = tbEmail.Text;

                // Add the member to the group
                m.AddGroup(addToMemberGroup.Id);

                //Save member
                m.Save();

                //Generate member Xml Cache
                m.XmlGenerate(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());

                // NOTE: This Is Optional
                // Login the user
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbUsername.Text, false);

                // Redirect to successful page (Usually their profile or member page)
                Response.Redirect(library.NiceUrl(SuccessfulLoginPage));
            }
            else
            {
                // Error, member already exists with email or username used
                litError.Text = string.Format(ErrorFormat, "User already exists");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am unable to understand why it is giving error
plz help me

Comment: You need to step through this code in debug mode in VS. Can you also provide the stack trace of the exception please?

Comment: how to do that
coz there is only intellitrace avilable

Comment: Use youtube when you want to know something on VS, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCPt9aOcd98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the Membership provider is set correctly in your web.config file as it seems that your `Member` instance is null.

Ensure that you are using the same config settings that Umbraco installed with. If in doubt, download your version again and check the original web.config settings.

**Update:**

Check that there is a default Member type set in the web.config:

```
<membership
    defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider"
    userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15"
    defaultMemberTypeAlias="SiteMembers"
/>
```

Comment: thi is the default provider and i also have same
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by just changing a statment in webconfig file

```
defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type"
```

**TO**

```
defaultMemberTypeAlias="SiteMembers"
```

SiteMembers is a type that ive created in umbraco backoffice

Comment: That is what I have said in my answer. You did not have `defaultMemberTypeAlias` set.